# Phpstorm Task Server cannot login to Youtrack Server

Tags: phpstorm, youtrack

I use Phpstorm 7.0 and have created a YouTrack InCloud account with the free plan.
When i enter my server and login in Phpstorm i get a 404 error. What i am doing wrong?

Server: http://st.myjetbrains.com/
Username: same as i use on the web interface
Password: same as i use on the web interface

Error Message after clicking "Test":
Cannot login: HTTP status code 404.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to use http://st.myjetbrains.com/youtrack, not just http://st.myjetbrains.com/.